# Why or how would adding an identity column to an inline index improve overall query performance?

Tags: sql-server, performance, indexing, query-optimization

My create table statement, which looks something like this:

```
declare @vTable table (
   col1   varchar(10)
  ,col2   varchar(20)
  ,col3   date
  ,col4   varchar(50)
  ,id     int identity(1,1) not null
  ,index idx1 clustered (col1 asc, col2 asc, col3 desc, id asc)
)
```

runs over 80% faster than this statement:

```
declare @vTable table (
   col1   varchar(10)
  ,col2   varchar(20)
  ,col3   date
  ,col4   varchar(50)
  ,index idx1 clustered (col1 asc, col2 asc, col3 desc)
)
```

and with 90% fewer logical reads.

The clustered index likely has *some* duplicated values, so I believe T-SQL will add a unique identifier when the index is being created. The only reason I can imagine that this is faster is because we're making the index unique by explicitly adding a unique identifier, though I'm not entirely sure.

Can anyone confirm or help explain why this would be so significantly faster?

Comment: You'd need to post the query and query plan to be sure, but it's likely that the id is needed to identify the row, so omitting it from the clustered index and not having a proper primary key that _includes_ the id column simply looks like a mistake.

Comment: Unlikely the `DECLARE` by itself is slow, presumably it's the insert. `IDENTITY` [disables parallel inserts](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/datacat/real-world-parallel-insert-select-what-else-you-need-to-know/ba-p/305329), so that may make a difference, although I believe table variables also do. Please share the execution plan via https://brentozar.com/pastetheplan